# Is there a Latin equivalent for "All talk but no action"?

Tags: idiom

There was a discussion about the phrase "Blowing your own trumpet" which according to some means same. But when translated to Latin idioms it steered more towards just being "too proud" or "praising oneself (too much)".

Comment: Maybe this answer can help those who know latin. In Portuguese, language with latin roots, we say *«É só garganta»* or *«Isso é só garganta»* which literally translates to *«That's only throat»* with that exact meaning of much talking, but no action.

Comment: *Blowing your own trumpet* means *too proud* or *praising oneself (too much)* in English, too. It really is not the same thing as *all talk but no action*. The former emphasizes that the person gives himself praise rather than either allowing his accomplishments to speak for themselves or others to praise him—but it says nothing about whether or not the accomplishments are worthy of praise, just that his self-praise is unseemly. The latter emphasizes the lack of action as the problem—the talk may be very well and good but without action it is meaningless.

Comment: @Edu Welcome to the site! I think your comment may be quite helpful. The reason we converted it into a comment is that the question above is "is there a Latin equivalent...?" (as this site is about Latin). So your reply falls into the category of comments: it does not directly answer the exact question, but it is useful in other ways, which is the purpose of comments.

Answer (score 5):

*Intoleranter se iactat*  (Cic. de Oratore II.52) is an accurate translation for *blowing your own trumpet*. [The actual passage runs *superioribus invidetur saepe vehementer et eo magis, si intolerantius se iactant et aequabilitatem communis iuris praestantia dignitatis aut fortunae suae transeunt*.]

*All talk but no action* is rather a scornful than a strong criticism: *Disertus sed agendo non capax* — rather like the Emperor Galba who, according to Tacitus was *capax imperii nisi imperasset*.